# Meaning of “in the evidence”?

Tags: vocabulary, legalese

I am not sure I quite understand the meaning of “in the evidence” in this sentence:

“The organization would feature in the evidence as an alleged MI6 front operation”.

Does it mean: “It turned out that the organization was a MI6 front operation”?

Searched sources: Oxford Dictionary; thesaurus.com; Webster Dictionary.

Comment: You will have to provide a little more context for this sentence. It looks to me as if the author is speaking of how the organization was perceived or depicted in 'evidence' presented at some sort of trial or hearing.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the meaning is literal.  In the evidence of the case in question.

Comment: True. I realized that on second thought — a clear example that, not being an English native speaker, I may not always clip instantly.

Comment: You'll get there!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this sentence is closing a whole paragraph about a political trial. “in the evidence” makes a clear reference to the evidence brought up to the court. In other words, “in the evidence” is not a set expression: as a forumer has put it, the meaning here is literal.